# Buckminster RCP simple project materialization

Tags: eclipse-rcp, buckminster

After watching the webinar, skimming over the BuckyBook PDF, and following the Eclipse RCP build tutorial, I still don't know how to materialize a simple RCP plug-in project from CVS into an eclipse workspace.

Does anyone have an example with a CQUERY and an RMAP file, for a simple one project workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually easy.

Here is a sample CSPEC:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cq:componentQuery xmlns:cq="http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/CQuery-1.0" resourceMap="example-site.rmap">
    <cq:rootRequest name="example-site" componentType="eclipse.feature"/>
</cq:componentQuery>
```

Note the root request name property points to a component. If you have an RCP app which has a main bundle (say one that is the launching point to your app), then you would point to this component using the name property above. This CSPEC will then download all dependent components using the RMAP below, using search paths, providers etc.

The RMAP:

```
<searchPath name="default">
    <provider 
    readerType="cvs" 
    componentTypes="osgi.bundle,eclipse.feature" 
    source="true" 
    mutable="true">
        <uri format=":pserver:anon@cvs.local:/opt/data/cvsroot,{0}/">
            <bc:propertyRef key="buckminster.component" />
        </uri>
    </provider>
</searchPath>

<searchPath name="galileo">
    <provider readerType="eclipse.import" componentTypes="osgi.bundle,eclipse.feature"
        mutable="false" source="false">
        <uri format="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo?importType=binary"/>
    </provider>
</searchPath>   

<locator searchPathRef="default" pattern="^example\-.*" />
<locator searchPathRef="galileo" failOnError="false" />
```